How to reenroll certificate on behalf of someone else? Windows Certification Authority
I have Windows Server 2022 CA with a configured Enrollment Agent.
I can enroll new certificate on behalf of another user but I can't do the same with renewing it, while logged on as the Enrollment Agent account on a client PC and having another user certificate with private key. I have AD domain.
Is there a possible way to achieve this?

Renewal on behalf of doesn't natively exist in AD CS architecture. The idea is that you perform initial certificate enrollment on behalf of using enrollment agent certificate as co-signer, then certificate is renewed by actual certificate holder using existing certificate via autoenrollment for example. Existing certificate is used as a proof that client is eligible for renewal and can bypass CA Manager approval and enrollment agent requirements for renewal. So renewal process can be automated and be silent.
If you need renewal using enrollment agent, then it is the same process as initial certificate enrollment on behalf of.
